# React list rendering wrong(cache)data after deleting item

Tags: reactjs

I have one add Room Popup in one React Component where a user can add one or more rooms and provide description of Rooms with some Input Fields.

The Add functionality is Working fine. But Suppose if I delete second Room(Room 2) after Adding Room1,Room2,Room3 with respective descriptions, the display shows Room 1 and Room2 instead of Room1 and Room3. I am also maintaining a array of objects to be sent as json to Service where each object represents one room and after deleting the Room2, array gets updated correctly with only Room 1 and Room3 data.The react re-renders the pop-up with console.log showing the array data of Room1 and Room3 but on screen only room1 and room2 data gets displayed.

```
getInitialState() {

    return {
         add_rooms:[{
        "resourceEmail":"",
        "resourceName":"",
        "resourceLocation":"Australia-Melbourne",
        "resourceType":"",
        "resourceDesc":"",
        "resourcePhone":"",
        "resourceCapacity":"",
        "systemId":"",
        "resourceStatus":"Y",
        "groupMailId":"",
        "resourceDropStatus":""
    }],
 }  
  },





        <Modal id="modal_edit" 
      show={this.state.show_add}
      onHide={this.hideModal}
      container={this}
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"> 

       <Modal.Body>
      <span className="popup_close" onClick={this.closeAddpop}></span>
      <div className="pop_head_edit">
        ADD ROOMS

     </div>
      <div className="pop_ul_div" id="add_modal" >
        {this.state.add_rooms.map(function(add,index)
                {

                    console.log("re-rendering");
                  console.log("addrooms",this.state.add_rooms);
                console.log("index "+ index);
                    return(<ul className="pop_ul add_rooms_ul" id={"add_room_list_"+index}>
         <li>
           <span>LOCATION</span>
          <select value={this.state.add.resourceLocation}  onChange={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"location",index)}>
             {this.state.room_locations.map(function(obj,ind){
             return(
             <option value={obj}>{obj}</option>)}.bind(this))}
          </select> 
                    </li>

          <li>
           <span>ROOM NAME</span>
              <input type="text" name="name"    value={this.state.add.resourceName}  onChange={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"name",index)}/>
         </li>
           <li>
           <span>ROOM DESCRIPTION</span>
           <input type="text" name="desc" maxLength="25"  value={this.state.add.resourceDesc}   onChange={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"desc",index)}/>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span>ROOM CAPACITY</span>
         <input type="text" maxLength="3" value={this.state.add.resourceCapacity}  onChange={this.handleAddCapacityChange.bind(this,index)}/>
         </li>
           <li>
           <span>ROOM TYPE</span>
             <select value={this.state.add.resourceType}    onChange={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"type",index)} >
             {this.state.roomTypeList.map(function(obj,ind){
             return(
             <option value={obj}>{obj}</option>)}.bind(this))}
           </select>
         </li>
                   <li>
           <span>ROOM STATUS</span>
            <select value={this.state.add.resourceDropStatus} onChange={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"dropStatus",index)}>
             {this.state.roomStatusList.map(function(obj,ind){
             return(
             <option value={obj}>{obj}</option>)}.bind(this))}
           </select>
         </li>

           <li>
           <span>ROOM PHONE NUMBER</span>
      <input type="text" name=""  maxLength="25"  value={this.state.add.resourcePhone}   onChange={this.handleAddNumberChange.bind(this,index)}/>
         </li>
           <li>
           <span>ROOM EMAIL</span>
           <input type="text" value={this.state.add.resourceEmail}  onBlur={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"email",index)}/>
         </li>
           <li>
           <span>SYSTEM ID AS IN CISCO TMS</span>
             <input  type="text"  value={this.state.add.systemId}  onChange={this.handleAddSysIdChange.bind(this,index)}/>
         </li>
          <li>
           <span>LOCATION IMG EMAIL</span>
           <input type="text" name="" maxLength="200"  value={this.state.add.groupMailId}   onBlur={this.handleRoomAdd.bind(this,"groupMail",index)}/>
         </li>
         <li>

         </li>
         <li>
           <button className="del_room" onClick={this.del_click.bind(this,index)}></button>
         </li>
       </ul>)}.bind(this))}
       <div className="add_room_div">
         <button className="add_rooms" onClick={this.add_click}></button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div className="footer_edit_pop">
       <div className="update_chk_bx_div">
          <div className="chk_div">
<button className="dwnld_img" onClick={this.saveAddPop}>SAVE</button>
<button className="dwnld_img" onClick={this.closeAddpop}>CANCEL</button>
    </div>

       </div>
      </div>
      </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>

            {this.state.loading?
        <div>
        <div className = "loader_react"></div>
        <div className = "loader_block_react"></div>   
        </div>
        :
        null
        }
     </div>


      )
  }
})


    add_click: function()
        {       
        var addRoom ={
            "resourceEmail":"",
            "resourceName":"",
            "resourceLocation":"Australia-Melbourne",
            "resourceType":"",
            "resourceDesc":"",
            "resourcePhone":"",
            "resourceCapacity":"",
            "systemId":"",
            "resourceStatus":"Y",
            "groupMailId":"",
            "resourceDropStatus":""
            };
            this.state.add_rooms.push(addRoom);


        },

 del_click: function(index)
    {
              //debugger;
                let mainIndex=index;
                console.log("mainIndex", mainIndex);
                  var rooms= this.state.add_rooms
                  rooms.splice(mainIndex,1);
             this.setState({add_rooms:rooms},function(){
             console.log("add_rooms",this.state.add_rooms);
              line 0;
             });        

    },
```

line -0:  /*After deleting a room in del_click, the add_rooms shows the two rooms that should be present and ADD-Rooms Pop up is re-rendered but it displays the deleted room minus a other valid room */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding a Room you are directly mutating the state and while deleting a room you are using `setState` which is what causes this issue.

React docs state that

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were
>   immutable.

You can add an item to the state array like

```
add_click: function()
    {       
    var addRoom ={
        "resourceEmail":"",
        "resourceName":"",
        "resourceLocation":"Australia-Melbourne",
        "resourceType":"",
        "resourceDesc":"",
        "resourcePhone":"",
        "resourceCapacity":"",
        "systemId":"",
        "resourceStatus":"Y",
        "groupMailId":"",
        "resourceDropStatus":""
        };
        this.setState(prevState => ({add_rooms: prevState['add_rooms'].concat(addRoom)}))


    },
```

Comment: Thanks for Clarification but the  Solution is not working...same issue comes again

Comment: Same problem, wasted my whole day and not solution yet!

Comment: @PavanGR could you post a question with your exact issue